# JSON GWT parsing error

Tags: java, json, gwt

I tried using the following method to parse my data:

```
public static <T extends JavaScriptObject> T parseJson(String jsonStr)
   {
      return JsonUtils.safeEval(jsonStr);
    }
```

It gives the following exception when I call the method as
`parseJson(response.getText())`

> java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to com.google.gwt.core.client.JavaScriptObject

I want to get values from the key in JSON. The JSONParser also returns a NullPointerException.

Comment: What language is this? I guess Java? Please edit your question to add an appropriate tag for the language.

Comment: @km1: what does your input string look like?

Answer (score 0):

I recommand using GWT-Jackson for Json parsing in GWT.

https://github.com/nmorel/gwt-jackson